# Joomla 1.5 native mod_search module to search only in current category

Tags: php, search, joomla, joomla1.5

im trying to upgrade mod_search in Joomla to display search results only from category, that user is viewing atm...

Ive managed to pass catid to com_search controller and model, ive tried to update search plugin's query, but still i can't get the results..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on debug mode in the /administrator/ area. Run your search in the front end of the site and check the debug output (at the bottom of the page). Check whether your edited sql query has been run and is listed in the debug output. Check the same query against the db directly - from a mysql command line or via phpmyadmin and see if there are any issues.

Which search plugin did you edit - was it the correct one, and have you accidentally changed the code so as to stop it returning results?

Comment: thanks for your reply Dean Marshall, i've already solved the problem, but your solution with debug mode is really great - never thought of that myself.